# Reading .stj with python?

Tags: python

I have a program written by someone in Visual Basic 6.0 and produces stj files(super trajectory files). I need to read it somehow and create a simulation. Is there any way to do this? I have been searching on the internet but nothing really comes out... Please let me know if anyone has any clue!

Comment: unfamiliar with this extension. I found nothing about super trajectory files, but stj did have some hits as a video container format. What kind of data is this you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: I was told that it is a binary file that contains columns of single precision numbers. It stores the data of positions and speeds of particles that the program traces.

Comment: if you know the binary format it lays out the data in, then you may have luck with python's `struct` library

Comment: okay, I will try that! Thank you